# issue with clear: right when use float:right

Tags: css

```
<style>
.floatright { float: right;margin: 0 0 10px 10px;clear: right;width:60px; height:60px; }
</style>
<img class="floatright" src="computer1.png" alt="" width="60" height="60">
<img class="floatright" src="computer2.png" alt="" width="60" height="60">
<img class="floatright" src="computer3.png" alt="" width="60" height="60">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
```

Question:

Here `clear: right;` will get the images to stack on top of each other, but why can not use `clear: left;`?, according to here:http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp, it is said:

```
clear:left,     No floating elements allowed on the left side
```

so it means if I use `clear:left` in `.floatright`, no floating elements allowed on the left side of each image, thus, all the images will stack on top of each other, but actually not, `clear:left` does not do anything, why?

Comment: Tried `clear: both;`?

Comment: Sigh. w3schools is wrong *again*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does what it says, the `clear` property just consider the *earlier* elements position, not the *following* elements.

> This property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) may not be adjacent to an **earlier** floating box [(W3C CSS specification)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control)

When you set `float: right` to all three image, the second image will be put in to **the left side** of the first image. The `clear:left` will consider the *earlier* element, here the first image, not the *next* element. So there is no reason why the third image must be put below the second image.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) (or at the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control) itself) if you want a decent explanation. W3Schools is a terrible reference.

`clear: left` won't work simply because `clear: left` only clears elements that are floating to the left. If you want to clear both directions, use `clear: both`.